# Increase session some value

Tags: java, html, jsp, session

I want to know if a user has 3 time failed to log in, then a `Help` link appears.

So i need to store some value in session and check its value (called `tryTimes`) each time user log in:

My code in `doLogin` servlet:

```
if (logedInSuccessfully()) { // OK
//create session and add sum attributes
    response.sendRedirect("Home.jsp");
} else {
    int i = 0;
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    session.setAttribute("existsInDB", "No");
    session.setAttribute("tryTimes", ++i);
    response.sendRedirect("Login.jsp"); // back to log in page again
}
```

In `Login.jsp` page:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Login Page </title>
</head>
<body>
    <%
        int tryTimes = 0;

    if (String.valueOf(session.getAttribute("existsInDB")).equalsIgnoreCase("No")) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No: " + session.getAttribute("tryTimes"));
            if (tryTimes >= 3) {
    %>
<a href="LoginHelp.jsp"> <font color="white"> Need Help? </font> </a>
    <%
             }
        }
    %>
...
//End of page
```

But, When i test `i`'s value, it is always `1` and not changes at all.

What is wrong with m code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because you put  `1` every time, you need to read its value and then increment

change

```
int i = 0;
```

to

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(session.getAttribute("tryTimes") == null ? "0" : session.getAttribute("tryTimes"));
```

and then on JSP you have `JOptionPane` which doesn't make any sense, you need to generate HTML for it

also on JSP you aren't reading session attribute into `tryTimes`